# Calculating successive derivatives of a monomial list using a Do loop

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional, procedural-programming

I've got the following monomial list:

```
monlist={c x^3, x^5, 4};
```

I need to compute the successive derivatives of that list of monomials such that when the derivative of all elements in the list is zero, the Do loop stops. For a single monomial it is easy to implement the Do loop with the If statement, but for a monomial list I don't understand how to do it.

My goal is to get the following list structure:

```
{{3 c x^2, 5 x^4, 0}, {6 c x, 20 x^3, 0}, {6 c, 60 x^2, 0}, {0, 120 x,0}, {0, 120, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
```

I thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Most@FixedPointList[D[#, x] &, monlist]
```

> ```
> {{c x^3, x^5, 4}, {3 c x^2, 5 x^4, 0}, {6 c x, 20 x^3, 0}, {6 c, 
>   60 x^2, 0}, {0, 120 x, 0}, {0, 120, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
> ```

---

**EDIT**

Using `While` and for the sake of comparison with the procedural approach:

```
monlist = {c x^3, x^5, 4};
dlist = {monlist};
While[Last@dlist =!= {0, 0, 0},
 AppendTo[dlist, D[Last@dlist, x]]
 ]
dlist
```

Comment: Nice answer, Syed!

Comment: With Rest and Most commands. It's perfect, thanks a lot, Syed!

Comment: Thanks for the accept and the feedback; Best Regards. Try: `FixedPointList[D[#, x] &, monlist][[2 ;; -2]]` as a variation.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility

```
 monlist = {c x^3, x^5, 4};
 NestWhileList[D[#, x] &, monlist, Total[#] =!= 0 &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

And in the spirit of procedural like programming, here is my version

```
monlist = {c x^3, x^5, 4};
First@Last@Reap@While[True, Sow[monlist = D[monlist, x]]; 
    If[Total[monlist] === 0, Break[]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am sure the `NestWhileList` will be faster for very long list but I did not do any measurements.